# Has Salesforce ever logged "Adds/Remove of Actions in Workflow" in Audit Trail?

Tags: workflow, email-alert, setup-audit-log

Today I found that when I **removed a Email Alert from my TimeBased-Workflow** 2 months back, there was **no Audit Trail Log item recorded**. And the **LastModifiedDate on WF had not been updated**. Making the change hard to find 2 months down the track.
To the point I thought I had not made the change 2 months ago at all.

I **added back the Action** once I realised what was going on (thank you 5 month old sandbox). And **again same thing** LastModifiedDate not updated and no Audit Trail log.
I also tested this as an immediate action (Email Alert) on the same Workflow and no luck there either.

Seems strange this would not have Audit Trail.
Salesforce's answer is this is "WAD" Working as Designed.
I find that hard to believe they would purposely design in a Flaw.
I will add more once SFDC come back with a better answer, because at the same time as telling me it is WAD, they also explicitly advised that adding an action creates Audit log (contradiction). So more to come...

**Has it always been this way?**

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce have advised that this is a bug. This Advise came directly from Salesforce Support after I logged a Case. But they are still confirming detail with higher level support.

This work Around is my idea to cover my back when working on WF Actions:
So for Now as a work around I will update the Workflow Description to record action changes.This will log into Audit Trail and change the LastModifiedDate.
I will not select as the answer until I get confirmation from Salesforce.
For now this is an answer, hopefully someone has a better answer.

Comment: This should really have been a comment not an answer or an edit to your original question.

Comment: Please include more detail about where you are getting your information from. What cam directly from salesforce? Was it from the documentation? From a support case?

Comment: detail added - Salesforce Support Case, and SFDC Agent Called me.